# mySQL not working anymore after I updated MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, mamp

mySQL serveur cannot be connected while apache server works fine. (everything was working fine when I used the previous version of MAMP) Here a message I got when trying to connect

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqlcheck: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL
server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to 
connect
```

By the way when I request an URL in local that does not require any DB connextion its working fine (seems obvious) and when it does require some DB connection I got the following message:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)
```

CONFIGURATION:
MAC BOOK OX S 10.8.5
MAMP 3.0.7.3
php 5.6.2
Symfony2

Comment: That would mean your MySQL is not running. Albeit, this is not really a SO question, more for ServerFault.

Comment: Did you try turning it off and back on again? (Stop then Start the servers in the MAMP Control Panel)

Comment: Verify if the [mysql service is running][1]:

    ps aux | grep mysql


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/408013/what-command-to-use-to-check-whether-mysql-service-is-available-on-a-mac-server

Comment: One of the many reasons why I don't use the congested environment that is MAMP. You might consider moving to a [package manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_package_management_systems#Mac_OS_X) that can handle this kind of updating better

Comment: Yes I start again and stop again but still not working with this new MAMP. (was working and still is working with the new one btw)

Comment: can you open phpMyAdmin???

Comment: then the issue is symfony connected,.... have you rechecked your connection settings are the values in the parameters really identical with the ones set in mamp

Comment: I 've just reinstalled MAMP. I could connect to mySQL. then I "stop the server". And then impossible again to connect. APACHE is OK but not SQL. by the way I have always the following message (I translate it in English from French so might not be exactly the same words in English version) "Apache cannot be started because the PORT 1000 is already used by an other application". Don't understand because Apache is working anyway and I do not use Port 1000 for apache but port 8888

Comment: @ Nickolaus / Sorry I was wrong phpMyAdmin is not working: **#2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).**

Answer (score 0):

Remove the files ib_logfileN (N being the number) from the MAMP/db/mysql56 folder then restart your MAMP.

If still not working then also delete the ibdataN (N being the number).